# JavaFX HTMLEditor - Drag and drop Images within Webview

Tags: image, javafx, html-editor

Cheers folk,

By default, the drag and drop of text works as expected in the web viewer of the HTML editor. However, if I want to move the position of an image that is embedded with HTML code, it converts the image to the URL...

Do I really need to implement or modify the 6 drag listeners (for example OnDragDetected, OnDragDone ...) of the webview or is there a more comfortable way?

Thanks for any help

Comment: Please add a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example. Without it, how do you expect to us to help you? Since it is your first question on SO, you might read [the guide on asking good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: It is a very theoretical question, since the moving of text also manages without the implementation of a listener, but does not respond as desired to images. So before I start using the above listeners, I would have liked to know if this is the right way to do it. :(

Comment: Without code, without a reasonable attempt there is no way to help.